# How to Render and Blend Multiple Frames to a Buffer in Unity?

Tags: unity, frame-buffer

I was wondering if anyone knew how to render multiple frames from a camera or texture to a buffer in Unity and to then blend them together? Is this possible? If so how would I go about doing so in Unity?

Answer (score 1):

The [Image Effects](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/comp-ImageEffects.html) source code should give you a good idea how to render into a render target. You can import the package and look through the source code to get an idea of how they happen.

The basics are:

- render a quad that covers the full size of the render target
- the shader does the blending you're talking about by using the previous 
  render target texture(s) as input
- the output goes into a new render target, which can then be used as input for the next